# JSON.NET without classes

Tags: json.net

I have a component that acts as a middle man between 2 web services.  Both of them communicate using JSON.

The data that goes back and forth from the web services is very similar.  However, it does need to be massaged a little.

I currently have this working by deserializing the JSON, build a new JObject and serialize it.  It seems like there should be better way.

I'm looking at JsonConvert, JsonConverter, JsonSerializer, JsonReader, etc. trying to see if there's a better way to do this.

Any guidance on what classes to use/override to make this process more efficent?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue so that it can be analyzed and a potential solution derived.

Comment: You write, *It seems like there should be better way*.  What exactly is the problem with the current way you are doing things?  Excessive memory use dealing with huge JSON payloads?  Performance?  Maintainability?

Comment: How different are the JSON structures that both sides need?  Can you maybe show some samples of the JSON and the code you are using to do the translation?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom JsonConverter using the approach described in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), so you'll only have one concrete class, but this class can translate to a slightly different JSON representation of your object.

Another, more verbose, blog post about writing custom JsonConverters can be found here: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/